# PHP/SQL PDO Prepare/Execute Insert Statement not Working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

So I'm trying to use PDO objects on my site instead of the old method (especially since I heard it is better for and am in the process of updating a bunch of queries. But for some reason, I can not get prepare/execute to work no matter what I do.

dbconnect.php:

```
try {
    $main = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$dbmain;host=$dbhost", $dbuser, $dbpassword);
    $tracker = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$dbtracker;host=$dbhost", $dbuser, $dbpassword);
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $ex->getMessage();
}
```

tracker.php

```
include 'dbconnect.php';

$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; //Get page name
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];   //Get the IP address
$browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; //Get the browser name

if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    $referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; //Get the page the visitor came from
}
else { //If not refered from any page, referer should be blank or error occurs
    $referer = "";
}

$result = $tracker->prepare("INSERT INTO 'pages' ('page', 'ip', 'browser', 'referer') VALUES (:page, :ip, :browser, :referer)");
$result->execute(
            array(
                ':page' => $page,
                ':ip' => $ip,
                ':browser' => $browser,
                ':referer' => $referer
                )
            );
```

Secondly, could someone explain to me why I shouldnt use query() for everything? Right now I see that I should use query for non-dynamic queries, and prepare/execute for dynamic, but query works for both.

Thanks!

Comment: Any errors? What's wrong?

Comment: The whole point of using prepared/parameterized queries is so that you separate the data from the command.  This makes SQL injection attacks impossible.  If you use `PDO::query()` with arbitrary data, you don't have this separation, and SQL injection can occur.

Comment: @JohnVanDeWeghe, well, there are no errors showing, but the table is not being updated.

Comment: @Brad, oh! Okay, so that would be the equivalent of me using my previous method. Thanks.

Comment: @Brad sorry man, I tried removing my comment when I seen that, you are right, my bad.

Comment: @user2288151, Add this to get PDO to throw exceptions:  `$main->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`  Do the same for `$tracker`.

Comment: @Brad, when I do that, my site doesn't even load anymore, and no message is given.

Comment: Somewhere there has to be a message.  Look in your Apache error logs.  In any case, you *need* that on, so that it will have something fail if something goes wrong.  Otherwise you just have "It doesn't work but I don't know why."

Comment: @user2288151, That's because you have an unhandled exception now.  It's being logged.  Check your log files.

Comment: @AndyLester, oh my god, I can't believe I forgot to look at my error logs. I was looking at the folder where my includes are, instead of where they were actually being executed which is the main folder. It says it was a syntax error. that makes so much more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I see (*may could have other problem*) is you are wrapping column names with single quotes. ***Column names and Table names are identifiers not string literals***. If ever you have used a reserved keyword on them or the column name as well as table names contains spaces around them, they should be escaped with backtick not with single quote,

```
INSERT INTO pages (page, ip, browser, referer) VALUES (...)
```

- [MySQL - when to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/mysql-when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Comment: This worked! I honestly didn't know the difference between a backtick and single quote until I googled it. Can't believe it was that easy.